# How to structure Model and Service in Angular application?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-services

I have the following Angular 6 component to edit a Post:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'post-edit',
  templateUrl: './post-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-edit.component.less']
})

export class PostEditComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  categoryId: number;

  categories: Array<{ id: number, name: string }>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

When calling the API to get the data for the post with postId it returns:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "postId": 1,
      "title": "post title",
      "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
      "categoryId": 2,
      "created_at": "2018-10-20 10:14:23"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I created a PostService in Angular as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class PostService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  public get() { }

  public create(post) { }

  public getById(id: number) { }

}
```

**Question 1**

Should I define a model per component (edit, list, create, ...) as follows?

```
export class PostEditModel {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  categoryId: number;
}
```

**Question 2**

Should `categories` variable, that holds categories' list to display on an HTML 'select', be included in PostEditModel or just in the component as it is?

**Question 3**

The Post properties in PostEditComponent, or PostEditModel, are less than the ones returned by the API (example: created_at).

Should each service method has its own model? For example:

```
public getById(id: number) { }
```

Would return a PostServiceGetApiModel which when called by the PostEditComponent would be mapped to a PostEditModel.

What is the best way to do this mapping?

Basically I am trying to find the best solution for an application that needs to be able to scale ...

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1**

No. Just a single model with optional fields would suffice. For example, in add model, there won't be an id if it was generated online. So the model could be:

```
export interface Post {
  id?: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  categoryId: number;
}
```

Notice here that I'm declaring an `interface` instead of a `class` as [**Angular suggests**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-03) data-models to be interfaces instead of classes.

> Consider using an interface for data models.

**Answer 2**

I think the `categoryId` is already included in the model. So I'm not sure if there's a need to include the categories there.

However, I would suggest you create an `enum` for categories just for the sake of some strong-typing wherever you are assigning or using the `enum`s.

**Answer 3**

I think **Answer 1** answers this one as well. The Post model can contain all the fields related to a post that is present in any of the Post's CRUD Operation. So if some are present in all the stages of the CRUD, just keep them mandatory and rest as optional. So `created_at` can be optional

Comment: In relation to your "Answer 2" categories are the list of all categories which I will get from the Category Api using a service. So on the component HTML I will have a Select where the options are those categories and categoryId is the current selected option but that the user can change. Does it make sense? So the question was: should this property be in the model? I believe it should not. It should be only a property on the component.

Comment: In relation to your "Answer 1" I named the model PostEditModel and not Post because on another component, for example, PostListComponent the properties of the Posts displayed maybe only the titles. So the question is: Should I use a Model per component? What this assures is that each model as a clear relation with the component HTML. Having 10 Post components sharing a common Post model makes sense? Of course it is less work ...

Comment: The string value of the category should not be on the component, But the categoryId should be, as it is meant to be a part of the actual Post so it should be on the data model as well. Are we on the same page with this?

Comment: Yes, categoryId on the model. Category text and all categories options just a property of the component.

Comment: I think it does make sense to me. Because from what you're saying, if we have say around 20 components, displaying different sets of fields of the component, create a specific data model for each of them would make no sense at all(just my perspective.)

Comment: @SiddAjamera so your PostModel would be the same for PostUpdateComponent and PostListComponent? Is makes sense in some way ... But when scaling the application if many components use different shapes of the PostModel then it might be strange. As in fact the PostModel will need to reflect exactly what the API returns to satisfy all components. So it will closer to the API model then to the DOM model of each component.

Comment: For PostList, it would there would be a `Post[]`

Comment: Correct ... But imagine that each Post in Post List has extra fields even related to actions than Post Update does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182152/discussion-between-siddajmera-and-miguel-moura).

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1**

One model per one component. Whatever your files right now for **Post** module is perfectly fine.

Each module should have following files : 
 - Component
 - Service
 - Model
 - Module
 - Route

**Answer 2**

No.

Categories, I believe are list from which you will be selecting single/multiple category while Add/Edit Post. It should be in Post component only. Also i think it should come from service - backend so no need to maintain changes in list at frontend.

**Answer 3**

No.

I think we have covered this in **Answer 1**.

**Suggestion**

Apart from you question = It is better to create only PostComponent which includes both 
PostEditComponent OR PostAddComponent. You can handle it easily with Angular. You just have to check param in route.

Comment: A question about your Answer 1: Usually I associate a Module per HTML page. For example, if I have a page named Dashboard where I show a list of Users and a list of Posts then I will have the DashboardModule.with DashboardComponent. And on the same folder I will have the DashboardUserListComponent and the DashboardPostListComponent. If, for example, the Post component is used on other pages I then rename the DashboardPostListComponent to PostListComponent, add its own module, and move it to a share folder. Then I will reuse it in different pages.

Comment: In relation to services I make all them shared. So I have UserService that is used by many components but on each component I map the Service response to the component model ... But I do this inside the component not inside the service as it needs to satisfy different components so different models. Does this make sense?

Comment: Perfect! We are doing the same way.